# Django Issues - Adding a product

Tags: python, django, web

I'm currently learning how to create websites using Django. I followed a tutorial on Youtube and came across an error that I don't really understand. I was on the admin page and [tried to add products to my site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRy3q.png). This is the error I received after clicking Save:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FZoZT.png). I hope this is enough information to solve the issue. If anyone has an answer could you please make it somewhat easy to understand. I'm just starting and probably won't understand some terms. Thank you!

Comment: you need to run migrations

Comment: you can run migrations by `python manage.py makemigrations` then `python manage.py migrate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using SQLite3 for Database. I'm searching in Django bugs, that issues because of Sqlite3 update. 
Just install Django version >= 2.1.5, Delete file .db and migrate again

Answer (score 0):

Which tutorial were you following? it might've been something you did right before that.

I got an error similar to that a couple months ago when I was following a Django tutorial from CodingEntrepeneurs, and the reason was that I deleted the db file and some other files and nothing worked even after running migrations, so I had to create a new project.

Comment: I was following Mosh on YouTube. I resolved the issue though. I needed to update my Django and migrate again. Thank you though!